# Free in app payment in game IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xamarin.ios

In my game, I want to mix free in app payment and 0.99$ in app payment.

I mean to continue to level 2, user needs to pay 0.99$ using in app payment.
But level 3 and 4 are free of charge and level 5 costs 0.99$.

I need to know from IOS server or save in database if user gets level 3 or 4 to restore the game if it was uninstalled.

I know I can get purchased items from IOS server when they are paid, but I don't know if it's possible to get an item that was purchased for free or even if it's possible to purchase an item for free using in app payment.

Maybe I need to get some user info and save to my database to track its state.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Maybe you need to do some research. :)

Comment: I tried without success. So I ask the community !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consumable an Non-Consumable In-App Purchase can't be Free. You have to choice a price (0.99$ minimum)

I think you have to make one IAP with levels 2, 3 and 4. And an other one with levels 5 (and perhaps 6 and 7).

Comment: Ok, but how do I know the last level played. For instance, level 3 or 4. Where and how can I store user data outside the phone ? Can I get a userId somewhere from IOS server or have I to provide my custom sign up/sign in which would be a boring user experience?

Comment: You could create a minimal API to track what levels the users are on. Just call this API when the user completes a level, and store the users' progress in a database tied to their UDID (the iPhone's unique identifying number).

Comment: benwad, I already thought about your UDID idea, but it's a phone identifier and I need a user identifier: if the user migrates to a new iphone, I won't be able to update the score or the level 3 or 4 currently available.

Comment: The correct way to track this would be to use iCloud. Would be instantly available on all user's devices, and if user deletes the app data won't be lost. UDID is going away in iOS6, and your app will be rejected if you try to use it.